# sf command is not installed on linux

Tags: cli, sf

H, I have followed instructions on this site to install sfdx on linux, which is working fine
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm

but on the website is stated that the `sf` cli command is also bundled and installed within the tar file, but sf is not installed. I am asking on what additional steps do I need to take to install `sf` as the `sfdx` command will be deprecated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any extra steps to install `sf`.

From Docs:

> Salesforce CLI is a bundle of two executables: sf and sfdx.

more information on https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/README.md

For eg: going forward instead of firing :

`sfdx force:org:display -u nagendratrailheadcom`

you can just fire

`sf org display --target-org nagendratrailheadcom`

and it will display the same data.

Comment: yes, but i get: `bash-4.4$ sf version
bash: sf: command not found`

Comment: Can you share `sfdx version`, also hoping you installed using a tar file?.

Comment: sure! `bash-4.4$ sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.82.0-3d0c527ac6 linux-x64 node-v12.18.3` yes, I have installed it from tar file